# Python difference between data

Tags: python, mysql, string, execute

I have a Pyhton script that is pulling the cell value from the local MySql table but the data is not the same as a String.

For example, mysql value =  fromme@server.com

My original working method which functioned just fine was written as so:

```
chatFrom = 'fromme@server.com'
```

then I used this variable in my execute function as so:

```
chat.main(['-c', chatTo, '-u', chatFrom, '-p', chatPass, '-m', chatMessage])
```

Now I want to make the variables dynamic by using the MySql table:

```
chatToCursor = (cursor.execute('SELECT value from configuration WHERE label = "chatTo"'))
chatTo = cursor.fetchone()
```

and then use it in the exact same execute function but the problem I am getting is that the values are not the same somehow.  Python is complaining about the use of the "@" in the value.  Before, it did not complain at all as I suppose it was because "chatTo" was originally a string so it did not matter.

So even if I use str(chatTo) python still complains about the @.

The syntax of the execute command is as so:

```
chat.main(['-c', 'to@server.com', '-u', 'user@server.com', '-p', 'pass', '-m', 'message'])
```

so in my variable is the single quote also that is messing me up. How should I write this so that the MySql cursor is the same as the standard string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.fetchone()` always returns a tuple, even if there's only one element to return. So your `chatTo` variable is actually `('to@server.com',)`.

You would need to explicitly get the first element:

```
chatTo = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: that was it.  I was actually using the [0] in a print command below it. all I had to do was add it.  I will mark this correct as soon as Stack allows it.  Thanks for the quick response.